# string-match matches buffer contents, instead of argument string

Tags: string

I am trying to parse file permissions using string-match. My code is,

```
(setq fmode (nth 8 (file-attributes "/Users/sk/a.js")))
(message "file mode is as, - %s" fmode)
(string-match "^.\\(...\\)\\(...\\)\\(...\\)$" fmode)
(message "User permission -  %s" (match-string 1))
(message "Group permission - %s" (match-string 2))
(message "Others permission - %s" (match-string 3))
```

It outputs,

```
file mode is as, - -rw-r--r--
User permission -  (se
Group permission - tq 
Others permission - fmo
```

As one can see, instead of parsing the file mode string, `-rw-r--r--`, `string-match` parses the buffer contents from the beginning position.

My case is very similar to the documented example [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Search.html), but i am clueless why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string-match` works fine but `match-string` gets the group contents from the wrong object, namely the current buffer.

You **must** pass the original string to `match-string` as second argument.